# How to implement publishMode variable in configuration of SonarQube (v7.9.1 Community Edition) with GitLab

Tags: sonarqube, gitlab, gitlab-ci, sonarqube-scan

I'm using the latest version of **SonarQube(7.9.1) Community Edition**. I'm trying to implement sonar integration with **gitlab** and configuring .gitlab-ci.yml file for that. I need to use also **publishMode** variable which is in the list (https://github.com/gabrie-allaigre/sonar-gitlab-plugin) to be able to see the scanner results but i'm not sure how/where to place it. how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

The Gitlab plugin only supports SonarQube before 7.7 [due to the removal of `previewMode` from SonarQube core](https://github.com/gabrie-allaigre/sonar-gitlab-plugin/issues/222#issuecomment-477389825).

You'll either need to downgrade to an older SonarQube version, switch to SonarQube developer edition once they [introduce their Gitlab support](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MMF-1787), or look at using sonarqube-community-branch-plugin once they [release support for Gitlab analysis](https://github.com/mc1arke/sonarqube-community-branch-plugin/pull/34)